# How to join Scanner input seperated by comma and write it into a file in java

Tags: java

I want to give three-input from system keyboard using Scanner and write them in a file using BufferWritter.But the problem is that i want to join those input using comma(,).So how to join those input and write them in file in JAVA

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  For the answer, how about `str1 + "," + str2 + "," + str3` ?

Comment: And write to file using PrintWriter.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way:

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    FileWriter f;
    BufferedWriter b;
    try {
        f = new FileWriter("file.txt");
        b = new BufferedWriter(f);

        String str1 = scan.nextLine();
        String str2 = scan.nextLine();
        String str3 = scan.nextLine();

        b.write(str1 + "," + str2 + "," + str3);


        b.close();
        f.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: But in this case the BufferWriter is replacing the previous lines with the new one...Is there is any solutions?

Comment: You mean, that you don't want to overwrite previously written lines? Just add parameter `new FileWriter("file.txt", true)` to constructor to add string to the end of file.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop in, get inputs and write to file as you enter.

```
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("c://dummy.txt");
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] inputs = new String[3];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

System.out.println("Enter "+inputs.length+" values: ");
for(int i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
    inputs[i] = scanner.next();
    sb.append(inputs[i]);
    if (i == inputs.length - 1) {
        sb.append(",");
    }
}

writer.write(sb.toString());
writer.close();
```

Increase the size of String array as your number of inputs increase

Answer (score 0):

Look up String.concat method. Or do what Tim said...